# accessing a variable inside a ajax.done request to use in a Constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am trying to access a var inside a ajax done function to use in a constructor if possible. I am working on a project with google maps and need to display one piece of data inside of an infowindow. I can access what I need per marker with the request and log it to the console but I can't seem to properly access it outside of the done function. It gives me a NAN response in the info window but logs the correct information. [Here](https://github.com/monkeyshoulders/neighborhood-project) is a link to the repository(its scary code i know). This is last piece of the puzzle for my capstone project.

Comment: Your problem is variable scope. Read this documentation for some suggestions        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/variable-scope-javascript

Answer (score 0):

the code inside your `done` function is only within the `function's scope` or function's body however you want to use it outside.

Actually Ajax call is a `synchronous` which will execute and don't block code execution or don't wait for the done to be executed first.

To be able to do you functionality move your code that comes after Ajax  inside `done` method itself.

Comment: I'm calling the infowindow twice. once on the marker and then again on the list of items. I dont think that I can pull all of this inside the ajax call because it will break the functionality and then not pass. but im probably wrong